# Plugin To Update Configurable Product Attributes

Tags: product, configurable-product, backend, plugin

I have looked all over Google for something like this, but I cant seem to find this. I know I can do it programatically or via the database, but I wouldn't trust anyone else doing this apart from me, but I've got around 100+ products that require a new selection on the front end.

So far we have Size selection, but we also need a finish selection on the front end. Now I have 3 options:

1. Delete the current product and start from scratch
2. Create a script that does this
3. PHPMyAdmin modification

2-3 are out the question, as I would like others to do this too, so a backend plugin would be perfect (if there are any?)

1. This may have to be a possibility, but with so many images and categories to save out and re-upload and apply, this will become quite time consuming.

There must be something out there?